# `gnome-keyring-daemon` hangs if I log out & then log in again

Tags: gnome-keyring

When I start my computer (an up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04), and log in and do a days work, everything's fine. I then log out, and leave the computer on while no-one logs in. The next morning I log in again, and `gnome-keyring-daemon` is running at 100% CPU. SSHing will hang without connecting, because it's trying to unlock the appropriate ssh private key, and gpg won't decrypt anything, again waiting for a private key to be unlocked.

If I restart the computer, everything works fine. This happens all the time for the last several months.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good programmatic answer, but I've found that if I open a terminal window and 'kill -9 processnumber' that will terminate the process. It apparently restarts by itself and frees up the connection.